# Why does this bound of integration become pi/4?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

Perhaps it is something easy that I am not seeing but I cannot seem to understand why, in this integral, **a** changes to $\frac\pi4$

3$\int_0^a$$\frac {dx}{\sqrt {a^2+x^2}}$

I was able to solve the integral but am stuck on why I needed to change **a** to $\frac\pi4$. Is it assumed **a**=1? Thanks

Edit: This integral is solved using trig substitution. My question was only about why the upper bound **a** is changed to $\frac\pi4$ instead of another value after doing the trig sub. The question was answered by Travis below.

Comment: You question is not clear at all. You do not need to change $a$ to anything in general

Comment: Are you using some change of variable?

Comment: Presumably you are approaching the integral via $u$-substitution.  When changing from an integral $\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx$ to $\int f(u)du$, the original limits were in terms of $x$ values, and the limits of the new form will be in terms of $u$ values.

Comment: $x=a\tan u$, $0<x<a$, hence $0<u<\pi/4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the substitution made in the given solution is the standard trigonometric substitution $$x = a \tan \theta, \qquad dx = a \sec^2 \theta \,d\theta ,$$ which eliminates the radical from the integrand. At the lower limit, we have $x = 0$, and since $\theta = 0$ solves $0 = a \tan \theta$, we can take the lower limit to be $0$. At the upper limit, we have $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$, and to write the upper limit with respect to $\theta$, we must solve $a = a \tan \theta$, or $\tan \theta = 1$, which has solution $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Hence, with respect to $\theta$, we write the integral as
$$\int_0^{\pi / 4} \cdots d\theta .$$

(This explanation brushes under the rug a technical point, namely that once we've picked the lower limit, we must pick a suitable upper limit, that is, we cannot pick *any* solution to $\tan \theta = 1$ for the upper limit. Since $\tan \theta$ is increasing and continuous on the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, and that interval contains the chosen lower limit $0$, we should take the unique solution to $\tan \theta = 1$ in that interval.)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because a change of variable was done:

$$x=a\tan u\implies dx=\frac a{\cos^2u}du\;,\;\;\begin{cases}x=0\implies u=0\\{}\\x=a\implies\tan u=1\implies u=\frac\pi4\end{cases}$$

so that

$$3\int_0^a\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=3\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{du}{\cos^2u}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2u}}=3\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac1{\cos u}du=$$

$$=\frac32\int_0^{\pi/4}\left(\frac{\cos u}{1-\sin u}+\frac{\cos u}{1+\cos u}\right)du=\frac32\,\log\left|\frac{1+\sin u}{1-\sin u}\right|_0^{\pi/4}=...$$

Comment: There's an error in the last step: careful, it's $\sqrt{1+\tan^2u}$ (with the square root), so that you should obtain $$3\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\cos(u)}.$$

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you very much, you're right. Edit now.